# 18.10 can't delete obsolete supercatalog file

Tags: package-management, disk-management, 18.10

18.04 - 18.10 upgrade had problems with being unable to rename `/var/lib/sgml-base/supercatalog`. I was able to get it out of the way by removing the `sgml-base` package with Synaptic (which also removed all the dependencies) then renaming directory `/var/lib/sgml-base`. I then successfully installed `sgml-base` and all the removed dependencies with Synaptic.

Now everything is working, but I still have the old `supercatalog` and the renamed `sgml-base` directory sitting out on disk. I can't get rid of it. I've booted from the live CD and run `fsck` on the file system (ext4 - nothing was found. I even rebuilt the bad sector file).

I'm logged in as root, working from terminal, booted on the 18.04 live iso. The filesystem is mounted as just a regular old filesystem - not boot, no chroot. I still can't get rid of the old `supercatalog`.

Can anyone please tell me why the obsolete `supercatalog` file cannot be deleted? I can't even rename the file (although I did successfully rename the directory containing it).